# Programmatically delete directory of cloned repository

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I am using `LibGit2Sharp` to clone a remote repository into the windows temp folder. After my script has completed, I want to clean up. However, I always get the following error:

> SystemError: Access to the path 'pack-efcef325f8dc897099271fd0f3db6cf4d9f12393.idx' is denied.

where `pack-efcef325f8dc897099271fd0f3db6cf4d9f12393.idx` is a file in `$local_git_clone_path\objects\pack.`

How can I completely delete all local leftovers of the git repo I cloned using LibGit2Sharp ?

Comment: Are you disposing the repository before trying to remove the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember having faced a similar situation.

And, as advised by @nulltoken, you would have to `Dispose()` the `Repository` before trying to delete the files that are being held by it.

`using` should be the best option.

```
using (var repo = new Repository(repositoryPath))
{
  //Your repo specific implementation.
}

//Code to Delete your local temp dir
```

Reference: [Clone Fixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CloneFixture.cs) from LibGit2Sharp

Comment: I am using LibGit2Sharp 0.27.2 and it looks like there is a bug - even when I dispose the repository, I still get access denied.

Comment: @LukasK FIles in `.git/objects` are marked as read-only, you need to adjust attributes before deletion, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098942/deletion-of-git-repository

Comment: @ChristianHeld sir, you are a hero [literally :-) ], thank you!