# Deletion of git repository

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Consider following program:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetTempPath(),
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()));
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

var testFile = Path.Combine(path, "test.txt");
File.WriteAllText(testFile, "Test file");

var source = Repository.Init(path);

using (var repository = new Repository(source))
{
    repository.Index.Add("test.txt");
}

Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

On deletion of repository folder I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` - access to one of internal git files is denied. Is there anything else I should dispose of in order to delete the folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there anything else I should dispose of in order to delete the folder?

Your disposing pattern is just fine. The mentioned issue has a different origin.

As stated in the **[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3(v=vs.110).aspx)**, `UnauthorizedAccessException` is raised when there's a permission related issue.

Indeed, Libgit2Sharp behaves similarly to git regarding this and marks files under the `.git/objects` hierarchy as read-only, thus the thrown exception when attempting to delete them.

In order to work around this, and ease the clean up phase when our tests are run, we've developed a helper method (ie. `DirectoryHelper.DeleteDirectory()`), which recursively unsets those read-only attributes and delete files and directories.

See the **[source code](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/df3b22a754ef56da8d7e3c330ce2d783c2b7982e/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/DirectoryHelper.cs#L69)** would you be willing to reuse it.